# jQuery: Not able to uncheck checkbox after binding click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

Using the `jQuery` Validation plugin as a basis, I created a function to validate fields without the use of a form. The function also binds events to form elements to perform the validation on-the-fly.

There are a few cases where the use of the form tag is not possible, hence this function was created.

Everything seems to be working correctly except that the checkboxes are uncheckable once they are checked the second time.

Please can someone let me know what I am doing wrong.

```html
  

<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery('#submit').click(function(){
            var options = {
                'name' : {
                    required: true
                },
                'email' : {
                    required: true,
                    email: true
                },
                'number' : {
                    required: true,
                    digits: true
                },
                'select' : {
                    required: true
                },
                'select-multiple' : {
                    required: true
                },
                'radio' : {
                    required: true
                },
                'checkbox' : {
                    required: true
                },
                'checkbox-single' : {
                    required: true
                },
                'multiple-emails' : {
                    required: true,
                    multipleEmails: true
                }
            };
        
            if(customValidation(options)){
                alert('Form validated!');
            }else{
                alert('Form not validated!');
            }
        });
    });

    function customValidation(options, bindEvents){
        var fieldsValid = true;
        bindEvents = (typeof bindEvents === 'undefined') ? true : bindEvents;
        var errorDiv = jQuery('#errorDiv');
        
        jQuery.each(options, function(elementIdorName, rules){
            var element = (jQuery('#' + elementIdorName).length) ? jQuery('#' + elementIdorName) : jQuery('input[name=' + elementIdorName + ']:first');
            var elementType = element.prop('type');
            var elementName = element.prop('name');
         
            var elementValid = true;
         
            // First remove any validation errors
            jQuery('.error-' + elementName).hide();
         
            jQuery.each(rules, function(rule, ruleOption){
                // Required
                if(rule == 'required' && ruleOption == true){
                    // Select
                    if(elementType && (elementType.toLowerCase() === 'select' || elementType.toLowerCase() === 'select-one' || elementType.toLowerCase() === 'select-mulitple')){
                        var val = element.val();
                        if(val && val.length > 0){
                            // Do nothing
                        }
                        else{
                            elementValid = false;
                        }
                    }
           
                    // Checkbox and Radio
                    if((/radio|checkbox/i).test(elementType)){
                        if(jQuery('input[name=' + elementName + ']:checked').length > 0){
                            // Do nothing
                        }
                        else{
                            elementValid = false;
                        }
                    }
           
                    // Text, Email, Number and Textarea
                    if(jQuery.trim(element.val()).length > 0){
                        // Do nothing
                    }
                    else{
                        elementValid = false;
                    }
           
                    if(!elementValid){
                        fieldsValid = false;
                        if(jQuery('.error-' + elementName).length == 0) {
                            errorDiv.append('<div class="error-' + elementName + '">' + elementName + '</div>');
                        }
                        else{
                            jQuery('.error-' + elementName).show();
                        }
                    }
                }
          
                // Email
                if(rule == 'email' && ruleOption == true){
                    if((/^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?)*$/).test(element.val())){
                        // Do nothing
                    }
                    else{
                        elementValid = false;
                    }
           
                    if(!elementValid){
                        fieldsValid = false;
                        if(jQuery('.error-' + elementName).length == 0) {
                            errorDiv.append('<div class="error-' + elementName + '">' + elementName + '</div>');
                        }
                        else{
                            jQuery('.error-' + elementName).show();
                        }
                    }
                }
          
                // Number
                if(rule == 'number' && ruleOption == true){
                    if((/^-?(?:\d+|\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})+)?(?:\.\d+)?$/).test(element.val())){
                        // Do nothing
                    }
                    else{
                        elementValid = false;
                    }
           
                    if(!elementValid){
                        fieldsValid = false;
                        if(jQuery('.error-' + elementName).length == 0) {
                            errorDiv.append('<div class="error-' + elementName + '">' + elementName + '</div>');
                        }
                        else{
                            jQuery('.error-' + elementName).show();
                        }
                    }
                }
          
                // Digits
                if(rule == 'digits' && ruleOption == true){
                    if((/^\d+$/).test(element.val())){
                        // Do nothing
                    }
                    else{
                        elementValid = false;
                    }
           
                    if(!elementValid){
                        fieldsValid = false;
                        if(jQuery('.error-' + elementName).length == 0) {
                            errorDiv.append('<div class="error-' + elementName + '">' + elementName + '</div>');
                        }
                        else{
                            jQuery('.error-' + elementName).show();
                        }
                    }
                }
          
                // Multiple Emails
                if(rule == 'multipleEmails' && ruleOption == true){
                    var emailsArr = element.val().replace(/\s/g, '').split(/,|;/);

                    for(var i = 0; i < emailsArr.length; i++){
                        if((/^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?)*$/).test(emailsArr[i])){
                            // Do nothing
                        }
                        else{
                            elementValid = false;
                        }
                    }
           
                    if(!elementValid){
                        fieldsValid = false;
                        if(jQuery('.error-' + elementName).length == 0) {
                            errorDiv.append('<div class="error-' + elementName + '">' + elementName + '</div>');
                        }
                        else{
                            jQuery('.error-' + elementName).show();
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
         
            if(bindEvents){
                var currentOption = {};
                currentOption[elementIdorName] = rules;
          
                // Bind events to validate on the fly
                switch(elementType){
                    case 'text':
                    case 'email':
                    case 'number':
                    case 'textarea':
                        element.unbind('keyup.customValidation-' + elementName).bind('keyup.customValidation-' + elementName, function(e){
                            return customValidation(currentOption, false);
                        });
                        break;
                    case 'radio':
                    case 'checkbox':
                        jQuery('input[name=' + elementIdorName + ']').each(function (){
                            jQuery(this).unbind('click.customValidation-' + elementName).bind('click.customValidation-' + elementName, function(e){
                                return customValidation(currentOption, false);
                            });
                        });
                        break;
                    case 'select':
                    case 'select-one':
                    case 'select-multiple':
                        element.unbind('change.customValidation-' + elementName).bind('change.customValidation-' + elementName, function(e){
                            return customValidation(currentOption, false);
                        });
                        break;
                }
            }
        });
        
        return fieldsValid;
    }
</script>
<body>
    <div id="errorDiv">
    </div>
    <br />
    <br />
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" />
    <br />
    <br />
    <input type="email" name="email" id="email" />
    <br />
    <br />
    <input type="number" name="number" id="number" />
    <br />
    <br />
    <select name="select" id="select">
        <option></option>
        <option>Option 1</option>
        <option>Option 2</option>
        <option>Option 3</option>
    </select>
    <br />
    <br />
    <select name="select-multiple" id="select-multiple" multiple>
        <option></option>
        <option>Option 1</option>
        <option>Option 2</option>
        <option>Option 3</option>
        <option>Option 4</option>
        <option>Option 5</option>
        <option>Option 6</option>
    </select>
    <br />
    <br />
    <input type="radio" name="radio" />Yes
       <input type="radio" name="radio" />No
       <br />
    <br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" />Yes
       <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" />No
       <br />
    <br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-single" id="checkbox-single" />No
       <br />
    <br />
    <textarea name="multiple-emails" id="multiple-emails"></textarea>
    <br />
    <br />
    <button id="submit">Submit</button>
</body>
</html>
```

[Example on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wwwescape/sdhjpave/)

Comment: it reproduced for me only after submitting the form, if that's a case maybe you can just unbind all events after alert 'Form not validated!' ?
e.g.
    $("input[type='checkbox']").unbind();

Comment: but i need the events for the on-the-fly validation...

Comment: while un checking the checkboxes you are returning false which is stopping the default behavior of  checkbox to uncheck on 2nd click.
Instead of returning false, return some string like "error" and check on that to show error

Comment: you're right... will update my code in an answer... thanks... :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Sandeeproop correctly pointed out, the on-the-fly events were return false which weren't allowing the checkboxes to be unchecked. All I need to do was not return anything in the click event. Updated my code below and also updated the JSFiddle example.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <style>
        #errorContainer { color: #ff0000; }
    </style>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function() {
            jQuery('#submit').click(function(){
                var options = {
                    'name' : {
                        required: true
                    },
                    'email' : {
                        required: true,
                        email: true
                    },
                    'number' : {
                        required: true,
                        digits: true
                    },
                    'select' : {
                        required: true
                    },
                    'select-multiple' : {
                        required: true
                    },
                    'radio' : {
                        required: true
                    },
                    'checkbox' : {
                        required: true
                    },
                    'checkbox-single' : {
                        required: true
                    },
                    'multiple-emails' : {
                        required: true,
                        multipleEmails: true
                    }
                };

                if(customValidation(options)){
                    alert('Form validated!');
                }else{
                    alert('Form not validated!');
                }
            });
        });

        function customValidation(options){
            var fieldsValid = true;
            var errorMessages = jQuery('#errorMessages');

            jQuery.each(options, function(elementIdorName, rules){
                var element = (jQuery('#' + elementIdorName).length) ? jQuery('#' + elementIdorName) : jQuery('input[name=' + elementIdorName + ']:first');
                var elementType = element.prop('type');
                var elementName = element.prop('name');

                var elementValid = true;

                // First remove any validation errors
                jQuery('.error-' + elementName).hide();

                jQuery.each(rules, function(rule, ruleOption){
                    // Required
                    if(rule == 'required' && ruleOption == true){
                        // Select
                        if(elementType && (elementType.toLowerCase() === 'select' || elementType.toLowerCase() === 'select-one' || elementType.toLowerCase() === 'select-mulitple')){
                            var val = element.val();
                            if(val && val.length > 0){
                                // Do nothing
                            }else{
                                elementValid = false;
                            }
                        }

                        // Checkbox and Radio
                        if((/radio|checkbox/i).test(elementType)){
                            if(jQuery('input[name=' + elementName + ']:checked').length > 0){
                                // Do nothing
                            }else{
                                elementValid = false;
                            }
                        }

                        // Text, Email, Number and Textarea
                        if(jQuery.trim(element.val()).length > 0){
                            // Do nothing
                        }else{
                            elementValid = false;
                        }

                        if(!elementValid){
                            fieldsValid = false;
                            if(jQuery('.error-' + elementName).length == 0) {
                                errorMessages.append('<div class="error-' + elementName + '">' + elementName + '</div>');
                            }else{
                                jQuery('.error-' + elementName).show();
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    // Email
                    if(rule == 'email' && ruleOption == true){
                        if((/^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?)*$/).test(element.val())){
                            // Do nothing
                        }else{
                            elementValid = false;
                        }

                        if(!elementValid){
                            fieldsValid = false;
                            if(jQuery('.error-' + elementName).length == 0) {
                                errorMessages.append('<div class="error-' + elementName + '">' + elementName + '</div>');
                            }else{
                                jQuery('.error-' + elementName).show();
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    // Number
                    if(rule == 'number' && ruleOption == true){
                        if((/^-?(?:\d+|\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})+)?(?:\.\d+)?$/).test(element.val())){
                            // Do nothing
                        }else{
                            elementValid = false;
                        }

                        if(!elementValid){
                            fieldsValid = false;
                            if(jQuery('.error-' + elementName).length == 0) {
                                errorMessages.append('<div class="error-' + elementName + '">' + elementName + '</div>');
                            }else{
                                jQuery('.error-' + elementName).show();
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    // Digits
                    if(rule == 'digits' && ruleOption == true){
                        if((/^\d+$/).test(element.val())){
                            // Do nothing
                        }else{
                            elementValid = false;
                        }

                        if(!elementValid){
                            fieldsValid = false;
                            if(jQuery('.error-' + elementName).length == 0) {
                                errorMessages.append('<div class="error-' + elementName + '">' + elementName + '</div>');
                            }else{
                                jQuery('.error-' + elementName).show();
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    // Multiple Emails
                    if(rule == 'multipleEmails' && ruleOption == true){
                        var emailsArr = element.val().replace(/\s/g, '').split(/,|;/);

                        for(var i = 0; i < emailsArr.length; i++){
                            if((/^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?)*$/).test(emailsArr[i])){
                                // Do nothing
                            }else{
                                elementValid = false;
                            }
                        }

                        if(!elementValid){
                            fieldsValid = false;
                            if(jQuery('.error-' + elementName).length == 0) {
                                errorMessages.append('<div class="error-' + elementName + '">' + elementName + '</div>');
                            }else{
                                jQuery('.error-' + elementName).show();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });

                var currentOption = {};
                currentOption[elementIdorName] = rules;

                // Bind events to validate on the fly
                switch(elementType){
                    case 'text':
                    case 'email':
                    case 'number':
                    case 'textarea':
                        element.unbind('keyup.customValidation-' + elementName).bind('keyup.customValidation-' + elementName, function(e){
                            customValidation(currentOption);
                        });
                    break;
                    case 'radio':
                    case 'checkbox':
                        jQuery('input[name=' + elementIdorName + ']').each(function (){
                            jQuery(this).unbind('click.customValidation-' + elementName).bind('click.customValidation-' + elementName, function(e){
                                customValidation(currentOption);
                            });
                        });
                    break;
                    case 'select':
                    case 'select-one':
                    case 'select-multiple':
                        element.unbind('change.customValidation-' + elementName).bind('change.customValidation-' + elementName, function(e){
                            customValidation(currentOption);
                        });
                    break;
                }
            });

            return fieldsValid;
        }
    </script>
    <body>
        <div id="errorContainer">
            <div>The following field have errors:</div>
            <div id="errorMessages"></div>
        </div>
        <br /><br />
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" />
        <br /><br />
        <input type="email" name="email" id="email" />
        <br /><br />
        <input type="number" name="number" id="number" />
        <br /><br />
        <select name="select" id="select">
            <option></option>
            <option>Option 1</option>
            <option>Option 2</option>
            <option>Option 3</option>
        </select>
        <br /><br />
        <select name="select-multiple" id="select-multiple" multiple>
            <option></option>
            <option>Option 1</option>
            <option>Option 2</option>
            <option>Option 3</option>
            <option>Option 4</option>
            <option>Option 5</option>
            <option>Option 6</option>
        </select>
        <br /><br />
        <input type="radio" name="radio" />Yes
        <input type="radio" name="radio" />No
        <br /><br />
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" />Yes
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" />No
        <br /><br />
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-single" id="checkbox-single" />No
        <br /><br />
        <textarea name="multiple-emails" id="multiple-emails"></textarea>
        <br /><br />
        <button id="submit">Submit</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Updated example on JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wwwescape/sdhjpave/

Answer (score 0):

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery('#submit').click(function() {
    var options = {
      'name': {
        required: true
      },
      'email': {
        required: true,
        email: true
      },
      'number': {
        required: true,
        digits: true
      },
      'select': {
        required: true
      },
      'select-multiple': {
        required: true
      },
      'radio': {
        required: true
      },
      'checkbox': {
        required: true
      },
      'checkbox-single': {
        required: true
      },
      'multiple-emails': {
        required: true,
        multipleEmails: true
      }
    };

    if (customValidation(options)) {
      alert('Form validated!');
    } else {
      alert('Form not validated!');
    }
  });
});

function customValidation(options, bindEvents) {
  /***
  Function is based on jQuery Validation Plugin v1.13.1 but doesn't require a <form> tag
 
  Add custom validations in this function as required
  
  Currently supported validations are:
  
  Required - Field cannot be blank
  Email - Validates an email address
  Mutliple Emails - Validates mutliple email addresses
  Number - Validates a decimal number
  Digits - Validates digits only
  
  Todo:
  
  Equal To validation
  Allow specifying parent element for Checkbox and Radio elements to apply an error class
  Allow specifying custom error and success functions through function parameter and individual options   
 ***/

  var fieldsValid = true;
  bindEvents = (typeof bindEvents === 'undefined') ? true : bindEvents;
  var errorDiv = jQuery('#errorDiv');

  jQuery.each(options, function(elementIdorName, rules) {
    var element = (jQuery('#' + elementIdorName).length) ? jQuery('#' + elementIdorName) : jQuery('input[name=' + elementIdorName + ']:first');
    var elementType = element.prop('type');
    var elementName = element.prop('name');

    var elementValid = true;

    // First remove any validation errors
    jQuery('.error-' + elementName).hide();

    jQuery.each(rules, function(rule, ruleOption) {
      // Required
      if (rule == 'required' && ruleOption == true) {
        // Select
        if (elementType && (elementType.toLowerCase() === 'select' || elementType.toLowerCase() === 'select-one' || elementType.toLowerCase() === 'select-mulitple')) {
          var val = element.val();
          if (val && val.length > 0) {
            // Do nothing
          } else {
            elementValid = false;
          }
        }

        // Checkbox and Radio
        if ((/radio|checkbox/i).test(elementType)) {
          if (jQuery('input[name=' + elementName + ']:checked').length > 0) {
            // Do nothing
          } else {
            elementValid = false;
          }
        }

        // Text, Email, Number and Textarea
        if (jQuery.trim(element.val()).length > 0) {
          // Do nothing
        } else {
          elementValid = false;
        }

        if (!elementValid) {
          fieldsValid = false;
          if (jQuery('.error-' + elementName).length == 0) {
            errorDiv.append('<div class="error-' + elementName + '">' + elementName + '</div>');
          } else {
            jQuery('.error-' + elementName).show();
          }
        }
      }

      // Email
      if (rule == 'email' && ruleOption == true) {
        if ((/^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?)*$/).test(element.val())) {
          // Do nothing
        } else {
          elementValid = false;
        }

        if (!elementValid) {
          fieldsValid = false;
          if (jQuery('.error-' + elementName).length == 0) {
            errorDiv.append('<div class="error-' + elementName + '">' + elementName + '</div>');
          } else {
            jQuery('.error-' + elementName).show();
          }
        }
      }

      // Number
      if (rule == 'number' && ruleOption == true) {
        if ((/^-?(?:\d+|\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})+)?(?:\.\d+)?$/).test(element.val())) {
          // Do nothing
        } else {
          elementValid = false;
        }

        if (!elementValid) {
          fieldsValid = false;
          if (jQuery('.error-' + elementName).length == 0) {
            errorDiv.append('<div class="error-' + elementName + '">' + elementName + '</div>');
          } else {
            jQuery('.error-' + elementName).show();
          }
        }
      }

      // Digits
      if (rule == 'digits' && ruleOption == true) {
        if ((/^\d+$/).test(element.val())) {
          // Do nothing
        } else {
          elementValid = false;
        }

        if (!elementValid) {
          fieldsValid = false;
          if (jQuery('.error-' + elementName).length == 0) {
            errorDiv.append('<div class="error-' + elementName + '">' + elementName + '</div>');
          } else {
            jQuery('.error-' + elementName).show();
          }
        }
      }

      // Multiple Emails
      if (rule == 'multipleEmails' && ruleOption == true) {
        var emailsArr = element.val().replace(/\s/g, '').split(/,|;/);

        for (var i = 0; i < emailsArr.length; i++) {
          if ((/^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?)*$/).test(emailsArr[i])) {
            // Do nothing
          } else {
            elementValid = false;
          }
        }

        if (!elementValid) {
          fieldsValid = false;
          if (jQuery('.error-' + elementName).length == 0) {
            errorDiv.append('<div class="error-' + elementName + '">' + elementName + '</div>');
          } else {
            jQuery('.error-' + elementName).show();
          }
        }
      }
    });

    if (bindEvents) {
      var currentOption = {};
      currentOption[elementIdorName] = rules;

      // Bind events to validate on the fly
      switch (elementType) {
        case 'text':
        case 'email':
        case 'number':
        case 'textarea':
          element.unbind('keyup.customValidation-' + elementName).bind('keyup.customValidation-' + elementName, function(e) {
            return customValidation(currentOption, false);
          });
          break;
        case 'radio':
        case 'checkbox':
          jQuery('input[name=' + elementIdorName + ']').each(function() {
            jQuery(this).unbind('click.customValidation-' + elementName).bind('change.customValidation-' + elementName, function(e) {
              console.log(e);
              return customValidation(currentOption);
            });
          });
          break;
        case 'select':
        case 'select-one':
        case 'select-multiple':
          element.unbind('change.customValidation-' + elementName).bind('change.customValidation-' + elementName, function(e) {
            return customValidation(currentOption, false);
          });
          break;
      }
    }
  });

  return fieldsValid;
}
```